# Text in Title Bar

Tags: c#, visual-studio, winforms, titlebar

How can we move text in the Title Bar of a form in C#.net using VS 2008?

Comment: -1 for even the idea of purposefully building a horrible application.

Comment: Perhaps his question is something more like, "How do I align text in the titlebar" which doesn't seem quite so horrible?  (@Bombe, +1)  That question has been asked http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winforms/thread/9d0e10a1-2943-424d-8e04-34f5813cf602/

Answer (score 10):

If you want to scroll the text in the title bar (as in news tickers) you will need to update the title bar manually every second or so. You can use the [Timer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.timer.aspx) control for that.

Having said that, I personally find it VERY annoying to see such applications. You must have a good reason to do that.